# How to disable dissmissal of a BottomSheetBehavior, but still enable dragging

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a LinearLayout with `app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">`

I want this to allways be fully extented or collapsed, but never hidden.

I found the variable Hideable, and it helps, but sometime im still able to pull the bottomsheet below its collapsed state and hide it. It seems to be related to "flicking" the bottomsheet, since if i drag it slowly it allways work as intended.

A lot of questions here ask how to disable "dragging and dismiss" of BottomSheets but what i want is to only disable the "dissmissal"-part. I still want to be able to drag the bottomsheet to its collapsed state.

Is this not possible?